# Pandas sum values in a group within a group

Tags: python, pandas

First of all, sorry for the bad title. I will illustrate better here. I have a dataframe such as this:

| level 1 | level 2 | qty 2 | level 3 | qty 3 | level 4 | qty 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980 | 2302 | 1.2 | nan | nan | nan | ----- |
| 1980 | 7117 | 2.4 | 10025 | 15 | 2343 | 11 |
| 1980 | 7117 | 2.4 | 1221 | 1.3 | nan | nan |
| 1870 | 2333 | 22 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1870 | 7117 | 2.1 | 10025 | 12 | nan | nan |
| 1870 | 7117 | 2.1 | 5445 | 11 | nan | nan |

It is a flatten hierarchy that describe which components goes into a product. Level 1 being the finished goods (e.g. pizza) and level 2,3 and so on are ingredients used to make said product. I need to the following logic.

```
df_grouped = df.groupby (by = ['level 1'])

range = [4,3,2]
for group in df_grouped:
   for i in range:
      df[f'qty {i}] = df[f'qty {i-1}'] * df[f'qty {i}']/df[f'qty {i}'].groupby(f'level {i-1}')[f'qty {i}'].transform ('sum'))
```

Okey, so what I need to do if we, for instance, look at level 1 = 1980 and level 2 = 7117. I need to take 2.4 * 15/(15+1.3). The same goes for the row below: 2.4 * 1.3/(15 + 1.3)

This needs to be done for each level of each level 1 (product)

expected output:

| level 1 | level 2 | qty 2 | level 3 | qty 3 | level 4 | qty 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980 | 2302 | 1.2 | nan | nan | nan | ----- |
| 1980 | 7117 | 2.4 | 10025 | 2.20858895706 | 2343 | 15 |
| 1980 | 7117 | 2.4 | 1221 | 0.19141104294 | nan | nan |
| 1870 | 2333 | 22 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1870 | 7117 | 2.1 | 10025 | 1.09565217391 | nan | nan |
| 1870 | 7117 | 2.1 | 5445 | 1.00434782609 | nan | nan |

Comment: Can you provide the full expected output?

Comment: You can either _group-by_ multiple columns, or use a hierarchical index (aka, multi-index) to tackle that (afaiu).

Comment: I have edit the question to include desired output

Comment: And what's the problem now (with your code)? Does it work at all? And produces something that you don't want?